# CSS - how to add circle border/outline around circular images?

Tags: html, css, geometry

I've created a graphic using 4 images side-by-side to show a sales consultation process. I've used CSS to style them as circular images and added background image to visually link the images. Is there CSS to add a dark gray border or outline to each of the 4 round images?

See screenshot here:
http://www.floydtechltd.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Screen-Shot-CSS-add-circle-outline-border.jpg

See [www.floydtechltd.co.uk](http://www.floydtechltd.co.uk)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It works already with: `border: 10px solid #ccc;` because you set the `border-radius: 100%`

Answer (score 1):

```
#dslc-content #dslc-module-17 .liwo_process_block_image img {
margin-bottom: 16px;
border-radius: 100%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #B5A4A4;
}
```

use border: 1px solid #B5A4A4;